# How to test if a field exists in a feature?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcade

Is possible to test if a field exists for a feature in the visualisation profile ArcGIS Pro? In the Arcade Playground (https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/playground/) I've been testing various things using their default dataset.

`Text($feature);` returns:

`{"geometry":{"x":1000,"y":2000,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100}},"attributes":{"name1":"value1","name2":"value2"}}`

Yet calling `$feature.attributes` results in a field not found error.

`Find(Text($feature),"name1")` returns `-1` despite clearly being in the output of `Text($feature);`

Answer (score 2):

Always recheck your function reference. I had the arguments the wrong way round in find!

`Find(Text($feature),"name1")` returns `-1` but `Find(Text("name1",$feature))` returns `82` as expected. So this method can be used to determine whether a field exists. It still baffles me that there isn't error catching available in Arcade.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code to test for the existence of a field called zippy using Arcade. It works by accessing the [Schema](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/data_functions/#schema) of a feature.

```js
var b = False;
var dict = Schema($feature);
var arr = dict["fields"];
for (var i in arr)
  {
  var fDict = arr[i];
  if ( fDict['name'] == "zippy") {
    b = true;
    break;
    }
  }
if (b)
  {
  return "Zippy exists in FeatureClass"
  }
  else
  {
  return "Zippy does not exists in FeatureClass"
  }
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work in the Visualisation profile (Parse Error:schema is not available). It does work in the Field Calculation profile

Comment: @Georgeofalltrades apologies I missed that it was for a _Visualisation Profile_.  May be [Expects()](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/data_functions/#expects) is what you are after?

Comment: Not sure how Expects() would help - all that does is ensure that the attributes are made available to the renderer. Returning the value of Expects() always yields null even if the field doesn't exist.